# Transition Direction - Border

Tags: html, css, transition, direction

I'm having trouble with setting a transition, At the moment it goes from top to bottom (It's a border that shows when you hover). I'd like the transition to start from the middle and to spread to the side or at least to start from any side and to spread to the other...

My navigation menu anchors are using the navigation-link class !

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Futura;
  font-weight: 100;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../Media/body-bg.png");
}

/* NOTE: Class */

.navigation-box {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  min-width: 800px;
}

.navigation-menu {
  margin: 6px 15px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

.navigation-link {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-weight: 100 !important;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 0px solid DarkGreen;
  transition: left 2s, all ease-in-out 300ms;
}

.navigation-link:hover {
  color: Wheat;
  border-bottom: 3px solid DarkGreen;

}

.vline {
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cabinet Psychologie | 15&egrave;me</title>
    <link href="./Data/CSS/styling.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body noresize="noresize">
    <div class="navigation-box">
      <h1 class="navigation-menu">
        <a href="#" class="navigation-link" style="border-bottom: 3px solid DarkGreen;">Accueil</a><a class="vline"></a>
        <a href="./Data/Pages/cours.html" class="navigation-link">Cours</a><a class="vline"></a>
        <a href="./Data/Pages/plans.html" class="navigation-link">Plans</a><a class="vline"></a>
        <a href="./Data/Pages/plus.html" class="navigation-link">Plus</a>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

So if you know a way to make it work it would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider a pseudo-element to create the border. First you set 50% in left/right property and on hover you switch to 0 both and this will create the effect you want:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Futura;
  font-weight: 100;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../Media/body-bg.png");
}


/* NOTE: Class */

.navigation-box {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  min-width: 800px;
}

.navigation-menu {
  margin: 6px 15px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

.navigation-link {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-weight: 100 !important;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 0px solid DarkGreen;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation-link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right:50%;
  background:DarkGreen;
  transition: all ease-in-out 300ms;
}

.navigation-link:hover {
  color: Wheat;
}
.navigation-link:hover::before,.navigation-link.active:before {
  left: 0;
  right:0;
}
.vline {
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Cabinet Psychologie | 15&egrave;me</title>
  <link href="./Data/CSS/styling.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body noresize="noresize">
  <div class="navigation-box">
    <h1 class="navigation-menu">
      <a href="#" class="navigation-link active" >Accueil</a>
      <a class="vline"></a>
      <a href="./Data/Pages/cours.html" class="navigation-link">Cours</a>
      <a class="vline"></a>
      <a href="./Data/Pages/plans.html" class="navigation-link">Plans</a>
      <a class="vline"></a>
      <a href="./Data/Pages/plus.html" class="navigation-link">Plus</a>
    </h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, only one issue: I used a border to show which page was selected and now if I want the hover-bar to display right a the bottom of the navigation menu I must add padding pixels to my navigation-link class and because of that the border is displayed outside the green box, If you know how I can put a static green bar that displays on the selected page it would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: @Miloertas not sure i understand you well ... but in my code i created an active class to have the pseudo element always visible an thus the boder .. is this want you ? if not can you elaborate more, maybe with a screenshot

Comment: Sorry, managed to do it myself, I added an ::after element with the same property but without left and right at 50%

Comment: I just needed an extra class to show the user he was on "Accueil" or "Plans" like a permanent green bar for the page you're in. I've learned so much from your template tysm

Comment: @Miloertas no need to add after :) use the active class i created .. in my example i applied the active class to the first link to make the before element always visible

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `pseudoelement` instead of `border`.

To make it start from the middle, set `left` or `right` at 50% and give the `pseudoelement` a width of 0. On transition just increase the `width` to 50% and it will grow in that direction.

Adjust the `left` or `right` setting from 50% to 0, and increase the `width` to make it span the entire link.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Futura;
  font-weight: 100;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../Media/body-bg.png");
}


/* NOTE: Class */

.navigation-box {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  min-width: 800px;
}

.navigation-menu {
  margin: 6px 15px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

.navigation-link {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-weight: 100 !important;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: left 2s, all ease-in-out 300ms;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation-link:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: darkgreen;
  transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.navigation-link:hover {
  color: Wheat;
}

.navigation-link:hover:after {
  width: 50%;
}

.vline {
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Cabinet Psychologie | 15&egrave;me</title>
  <link href="./Data/CSS/styling.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body noresize="noresize">
  <div class="navigation-box">
    <h1 class="navigation-menu">
      <a href="#" class="navigation-link">Accueil</a>
      <a class="vline"></a>
      <a href="./Data/Pages/cours.html" class="navigation-link">Cours</a>
      <a class="vline"></a>
      <a href="./Data/Pages/plans.html" class="navigation-link">Plans</a>
      <a class="vline"></a>
      <a href="./Data/Pages/plus.html" class="navigation-link">Plus</a>
    </h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using :after or :before pseudo elements and by adding transform and transition property to it.

```css
  .navigation-box{
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  min-width: 800px;
}

a.navigation-link{
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.navigation-link:hover {
  color: #000;
}

a.navigation-link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a.navigation-link:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
 <div class="navigation-box">
  <h1 class="navigation-menu">
    <a href="#" class="navigation-link" style="border-bottom: 3px solid DarkGreen;">Accueil</a><a class="vline"></a>
    <a href="./Data/Pages/cours.html" class="navigation-link">Cours</a><a class="vline"></a>
    <a href="./Data/Pages/plans.html" class="navigation-link">Plans</a><a class="vline"></a>
    <a href="./Data/Pages/plus.html" class="navigation-link">Plus</a>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Thought there is one more problem now, none of the browsers will take account of "font-weight" so my font is now bigger, any ideas why this occures ?

Comment: I have a follow-up question regarding that one. What font family are you using?

Comment: I think I commented the wrong answer, actually, another suggestion was overwriting my font-weight property but yours is working just fine and I'm using it atm, so thank you :)